# JPopupMenu and Jmenu problem

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JPopupMenu` lets call it (aaa) inside it i have `Jmenu(mmm)` ,contain some `JmenuItems(like b,c,d,k)`.
this popup menu shows at right click on the panel ,and on mouse over mmm menu the sub `menu (b,c,d,k)` appear ,but if i goes down a little bit under the mmm menu ,the sub `menu (b,c,d,k)` disappear ,how i can solve this to be more friendly ?can i make the sub `menu (b,c,d,k)` appear with left mouse click over the mmm menu?

```
JPopupMenu aaa = new JPopupMenu();
JMenu mmm = new JMenu("mmm");
JMenuItem b = new JMenuItem("b");
JMenuItem c = new JMenuItem("c");
JMenuItem d = new JMenuItem("d");
JMenuItem k = new JMenuItem("k");
mmm.add(b);
mmm.add(c);
mmm.add(d);
mmm.add(k);
aaa.add(mmm);
```

Comment: An [sscce](http://sscce.org/) might help clarify your question.

Comment: could you reproduce your problem based on this example ??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574400/having-gradient-background-of-system-tray-context-menu/6574557#6574557, edit yout post and shows ...

Answer (score 0):

Not able to reproduce your problem. This is what I have tried:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JPopupMenu aaa = new JPopupMenu();
    JMenu mmm = new JMenu("mmm");
    JMenuItem b = new JMenuItem("b");
    JMenuItem c = new JMenuItem("c");
    JMenuItem d = new JMenuItem("d");
    JMenuItem k = new JMenuItem("k");
    mmm.add(b);
    mmm.add(c);
    mmm.add(d);
    mmm.add(k);
    aaa.add(mmm);
    panel.setComponentPopupMenu(aaa);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Nothing gets disappears. Is this the same you are doing?